# Expanding List in MAC Cocoa App

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, xamarin

Is there any way to create this Type control in Cocoa MAC app.[image]

Comment: I know there's an `NSOutlineView` that allows groups of related items to be in a tree view. Perhaps subclassing that would work?

Comment: Yes, But i want similar UI design. Same as image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSStackView`s for this. Use one for each group of items. 
Then place all stack views including your header views.
StackViews can easily show & hide single elements.

[InfoBarStackView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/InfoBarStackView/Introduction/Intro.html) is a nice example app by Apple, which does exactly what you need.